# Disabling HTML checkboxes programmatically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to optimize this ToDo app I made for practice.

#### My goal:

Prevent checkbox from being checked or unchecked and display an alert if .editMode class is present. **Then** when edit mode is "gone" have the program function normally.

#### My bug is:

While in edit mode, and the checkbox is clicked, it **does** prevent the checkbox from being "changed" and it **does** display an alert box how I want.  **However**, when you exit "edit mode", it does not allow any change to the checkbox ever again.

**Note:** edit mode is a class applied called: `.editMode`

I am trying to write a function that checks to see if the `.editMode` class is present, and then if it is present, not allow the checkbox to be checked or unchecked.

---

I wrote this code here, but it only works halfway (it doesn't allow the checkbox to be checked if `.editMode` is present, but then after you exit `.editMode` the checkbox still doesn't appear; like I broke the property from being present). Also, if I want to apply this to other areas of my code, I know I need to put it in a function, instead of how I have it written below to abide by *dry* programming.

```
var taskCompleted = function () {

  //List Item
  var listItem = this.parentNode;

  //Validation to ensure listitem is NOT in edit mode
  if ($(listItem).hasClass("editMode")) {

    //code to prevent checkbox from 'checking'
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (event) {

      //Checkbox Varible
      var $checkbox = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {
        $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
      }, 0);

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    alert("Finish editing the task before marking as completed!");

    //Mark as completed code
  } else {
    console.log("Task Complete....");
    //append the task list item to the #completed-tasks

    completedTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);
  }

}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffward01/qq202s3u/).

I am really at a loss of how I can do this correctly.  I can do it halfway which is almost more frustrating than knowing how to do it 100% properly.

I know instead of doing the code above, I should write a function like:

```
function isEditMode(){
if(edit mode present){
//prevent checkbox from being checked
//display prompt to exit exit mode
}
else {
return true
}
```

Another issue is I don't know how to 'disable' the checkbox without breaking that checkbox element permanently.  The code I did write above works, but then later prevents the checkbox from EVER being checked or changing states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you, rather than adding an `editMode` class and checking on it, to use the native `disabled` attribute of checkbox elements. You can easily disable the checkbox when the user clicks "Edit", and re-enable it when clicking on "Save".

Here's a quick example:

```
// When clicking the edit button
listItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").disabled = true;

// When clicking the save button
listItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").disabled = false;
```

Working JSFiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/qq202s3u/1/) (see lines 84 and 97).

Comment: Utterly amazing.  Thank you for the simple fix.  I was thinking WAY to complicated.